# cakephp hasmany query on same class

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

i am using this binding

```
$this->Company->bindModel( array(
        'hasMany' => array(
                'CompanyContactPerson'=>array('conditions' => array('Company.name Like'=>'%'.$a.'%'),),
            ),
        'belongsTo' => array(
                'Status',
                'User'
            )
    ));
    $this->paginate = array(
        'limit' =>20,
        'conditions'=>$conditions,
        'order' =>array('Company.id'=> 'desc') ,
    );
$all_companies = $this->paginate('Company');
```

It give this query as a result.

```
SELECT `Company`.`id`, `Company`.`user_id`, `Company`.`name`, `Company`.`status_id`, `Company`.`email`, `Company`.`modified`, `Company`.`created`, `Status`.`id`, `Status`.`name`, `User`.`id`, `User`.`roll`, `User`.`username`, `User`.`email`, `User`.`password`, `User`.`first_name`, `User`.`last_name`, `User`.`gender`, `User`.`address`, `User`.`city`, `User`.`state`, `User`.`country`, `User`.`modified`, `User`.`created` 
FROM `companyinfo`.`companies` AS `Company` 
LEFT JOIN `companyinfo`.`statuses` AS `Status` ON (`Company`.`status_id` = `Status`.`id`) 
LEFT JOIN `companyinfo`.`users` AS `User` ON (`Company`.`user_id` = `User`.`id`) 
WHERE 1 = 1 ORDER BY `Company`.`id` desc LIMIT 20
```

it make seperate query for CompanyContactPerson model. so as a result i got all result from Company table. I need only those rows from company table where CompanyContactPerson conditions is satisfied . how i achieved this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

put this in your Company model so it can have a relationship. :)

```
public $hasMany = array(
        'CompanyContactPerson' => array(
            'className' => 'CompanyContactPerson',
            'foreignKey' => 'ForeignKeyinCompanyContactPerson',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'exclusive' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
            'counterQuery' => '',
            'dependent' => true
        )
    ));
```

or put this to your CompanyContactPerson Model

```
public $belongsTo = array(
        'Company' => array(
            'className' => 'Company',
            'foreignKey' => 'ForeignKeyofCompanyContactPersonTABLE',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        )
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use limit in Query

```
'limit' => 2, //int
```

So only two rows will be returned.

Your code should be like

```
  'CompanyContactPerson'=>array('conditions' => 
                                          array('Company.name Like'=>'%'.$a.'%'),
                                'limit' => 2
   ),
```

Comment: what is this i dont need only two rows i need all rows with satisfied conditions

Comment: @DesertP , what is this ?? You didnt specify `$conditions` in your code .. Edit question to see what you wrote. And what is `CompanyContactPerson conditions`  ?? Where you have written in your code ?? What currently u r gettting as result?

Comment: @jQueryAngryBirds i got the solution. i will paste the solution in this post soon